# Is the formatting of my questions too long?

Tags: support, specific-question, quality-improvement

I'm a new user. Does anyone have any feedback on the format/structure in which I have asked this question?

[Locating specific instance of a class located using XPATH selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138565/locating-specific-instance-of-a-class-located-using-xpath-selenium)

I have done my best to explain the case as clearly as I can but I am thinking maybe it's a bit too long? I have noticed that shorter questions usually have more appeal and I have done my best to make it as concise as possible but it wasn't obvious to me how to explain this in a couple sentences.

Comment: Better to have to much description than too much code. My Python is too weak to tell if you have too much or too little code. You haven't padded the question with salutations, preemptive thank-yous, I'm a newb so don't hit me requests, or anything suicidal like "I need an answer NOW!" so you should be good on the text front.

Comment: Long or short, you can always apply the [inverted pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_pyramid_(journalism)) principle.

Comment: Please don't use bare tags in the title ("...selenium"). Either you don't need it (the tags in the Tags box tell users what technologies are used) or you can use text to incorporate the word more fluently ("... when using Selenium"). Note the change in case; these are trademarks and should be spelled as the company that makes them spells them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have noticed that shorter questions usually have more appeal

You're absolutely right. But that does not imply anything bad, it depends on the question. Essentially this can go two ways:

1. Your question CAN be asked in a short and sweet way, but you fill it up with a lot of fluff. This is self-sabotage, don't do that.
2. Your question needs a lot of detail to be answerable. Then great, add it. Not adding it would be self-sabotage.

The difference is that in the first scenario you make the reader do too much effort; you'll put off everyone including people who might be able to answer. Your question is competing with thousands of other questions, veteran answerers know not to waste their time when the question is deliberately wasting their time.

But in the second scenario the people that will be running away... are the people who are not qualified to answer anyway. Nothing lost, really. Some questions are more difficult than others, you can't really change the consequences of asking a more difficult to answer question. The main one being that less people will be able or willing to answer.